# Wordpress blog post image is not displaying on Twitter

Tags: twitter, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to display image of Wordpress blog post in Twitter card or in tweet with link. But I am unable to sort that issue. After doing a lot of research and many hit & try; I couldn't pull image in `twitter tweet with link`.
I am using `og:title`, `og:description` `og:image` along with twitter meta tags e.g `twitter:title`, `twitter:description` and `twitter:image`. I am also using `og:image:width` and `og:image:height`. I also tried many different sizes of image and did research about registered `https://` certificates but so far unable to figure out anything wrong.

Can anybody help me what's wrong with my content? Example effected url : https://www.kidpaw.com/blogs/top-10-best-history-channels-on-youtube-for-kids-in-2022/

Comment: There is definitely an SSL certificate issue with your site. The certificate chain is incomplete and it rates C on ssllabs.com with multiple quality problems. Twitter will not be able to crawl your site.

Comment: Issue resolved. Yes it was definitely SSL issue. Updating SSL certificate resolved it. Thanks